# Getting UItextfield value not using IBoutlet

Tags: uitableview, tags, uitextfield

I know this is a basic question but i´m a little confused, so i hope you can help me. I have a tableview with multiple dynamic tableview cells, and inside each tableviewcell i have multiple textfields. Each cell has a different tag and also the textfields and i want to access the uitextfields values as you can imagine. My problem is, i´m not using IBoutlet for the textfields (it would be a enormous amount of IBoutlets)...I´m using - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField...but i just can´t seem to make the correct connections in the IB, this is my code:

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

if (textField == [self.view viewWithTag:102]) {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

After this, do i have to connect the respective UItexfield (and all textfields) to self? and then, do i have to use the editing did end event?...

Regards

Comment: What?! but i up upvote the last time, check this: "You are welcome! If this answers your question, please accept the answer by checking the checkbox next to my answer and up-voting it so that I get credit for helping you. :) – lnafziger Aug 2 at 16:58"...this was actually you!, and then i pressed the button and an arrow appeared pointing up in your answers to me...What is going on?

Comment: Ok...know i understand...I need not only to up vote, but also put the "tick" on green color...sorry, i didn´t notice.

Comment: No problem, just trying to get you some more help!  I'll take a look at this later on if you don't get an answer in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that the answer to this question is another question:  What do you want to do with the text that the user enters?

I assume that you have some kind of data model that you want to store the data in.

If so, then when this function is called, you need to take the text that is already in the textField and save it to your data model immediately as it is entered.

For instance, you can access the text that was entered like this:

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == [self.view viewWithTag:102]) 
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        yourDataModel.stringToSave = textField.text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello inafziger, you were right i want to keep the values inserted in the texfields, so i have searched and i´m using textFieldShouldReturn method but only because the textFieldDidEndEditing(that i tried before) is not dismissing my keyboard, and i think it´s because of this explanation in apple library: "This method is called after the text field resigns its first responder status"...

Comment: after this i´m just thinking, that i will have a enormous! amount of strings that will old every value from each texfield on my tableview, imagine that i have a tableview that has 8 cells, and inside of them i have at least 6 uitexfields and on top of everything the tableview is dynamic...any ideas of how to simplify my life :) ?

Comment: Well, what do you want to do with the strings after they are entered?  Are you storing them to a database, or a file, or calculating something from them?  It's hard to say how to simplify things without knowing what you are trying to do.

Comment: The users enters all the data in the texfields, and at the end of the tableview he hits a save button, then he goes to another tableview(it´s not a single view app) and he does the same etc. So, i´m starting somewhere, saving the textfields data in strings and then for the save button, i thought i could save all the strings in one array...

Comment: Okay, figure out what you want to do with them first, and then do it whenever you get text from the text field.  If you want them to go into the array, create an array or dictionary in this view controller to add them all into,and add them as you can add of of the objects in the array to the "main" array when they hit save.

Comment: Thanks Inafziger, i appreciate your help.

Comment: Hello Inafziger, could you plz see below? i made a mistake and answered my own question :P